# Firestore query date range with using 'where'

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I need to grab doc from collection if its today and status true, but it seems not working is there any better solution for this query?

My query:

```
var query = firebase.firestore().collection("book")
query = query.where('completed', '==', true) 
query = query.orderBy('publishdate').startAt(1555567200000).endAt(1555653599999)
query.get().then(...)
```

I've also tried:

```
var query = firebase.firestore().collection("book")
query = query.where('completed', '==', true) 
query = query.where('publishdate', '>', 1555567200000)
query.get().then(...)
```

but no result

Comment: Did you create a composite index on that combination of fields? If not, the JavaScript console of your browser should show you a message that explains that this is needed, and a link that takes you directly to the console to create it.

Comment: You'll be billed for all documents returned from the server by `query.get()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to do two things to get this working:

1. Create a composite index by clicking on the link that showed up in my JavaScript console.
   [image]
2. Pass in the timestamp as a proper `Date()` instead of a number: `query = query.orderBy('publishdate').startAt(new Date(1555653600000));`

With that it works fine for me. See a working sample here: https://jsbin.com/gufogib/edit?js,console

Comment: Thanks, can you take a look my updated code solution?

Comment: My solution shows something that works. I don't think a workaround is needed.